# How can I use angular-cache in conjunction with the AngularJS LocalStorageModule

Tags: angularjs, angular-cache, angular-local-storage

I have an application that when it starts gets a list of admin users. 
The data looks something like this:

```
var users =
[
{"id":"527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4","name":"x"},
{"id":"966171f8-4ea1-4008-b6ac-d70c4eee797b","name":"y"},
{"id":"de4e89fe-e1de-4751-9605-d6e1ec698f49","name":"z"}
]
```

I have a call that gets this data:

```
 os.getUserProfiles($scope);
```

and the function:

```
 getUserProfiles: function ($scope) {

    $http.get('/api/UserProfile/GetSelect')
       .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.option.userProfiles = data; 
       });
    },
```

I would like to avoid the admin users having to continuously issue the requests to get 
the user list. I was looking at the $cacheFactory in Angular but this does not really 
seem to meet my needs.

The angular-cache that's on github looks interesting but I'm not quite sure how to use
it with objects like this and then have the data stored using the LocalStorageModule.

Can someone give me an example of how they have used this product with the LocalStorageModule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest check the extended [angular-cache](http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/).

As described in documentation: http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/guide.html#using-angular-cache-with-localStorage

```
app.service('myService', function ($angularCacheFactory) {

    // This cache will sync itself with localStorage if it exists, otherwise it won't. Every time the
    // browser loads this app, this cache will attempt to initialize itself with any data it had
    // already saved to localStorage (or sessionStorage if you used that).
    var myAwesomeCache = $angularCacheFactory('myAwesomeCache', {
        maxAge: 900000, // Items added to this cache expire after 15 minutes.
        cacheFlushInterval: 3600000, // This cache will clear itself every hour.
        deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive', // Items will be deleted from this cache right when they expire.
        storageMode: 'localStorage' // This cache will sync itself with `localStorage`.
    });
});
```

Or we can inject custom Local storage implementation

```
storageImpl: localStoragePolyfill // angular-cache will use this polyfill instead of looking for localStorage
```

I am using this plugin https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage, which is really simple to use, while providing full API.

Also check a local storage usage for caching the templates: [how to cache angularjs partials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229431/)

NOTE: This article [Power up Angular's $http service with caching](https://coderwall.com/p/40axlq), and mostly the section:
 **Advanced caching**, was for me *the reason to move to [angular-cache](http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/guide.html)*

#### How to create a custom Polyfill? *(Adapter pattern)*

As documented [here](http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/guide.html#using-angular-cache-with-localStorage), we need to pass the **localStoragePolyfill** implementing this interface:

```
interface Storage {
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  DOMString? key(unsigned long index);
  getter DOMString getItem(DOMString key);
  setter creator void setItem(DOMString key, DOMString value);
  deleter void removeItem(DOMString key);
  void clear();
};
```

> angular-cache cares only about these three methods:
>
> - setItem
> - getItem
> - removeItem

I.e.: Implement a wrapper talking with local-storage API, transforming it to the advanced cache api. That's it. Nothing else

Comment: @radim-kohlerim Thanks - Can you explain what is "angular-cache will use this polyfill" In your application, how do tell the cache service to use the angular-local-storage that you're suggesting?

Comment: I'e extended my answer. It is not so difficult. In fact it is pretty great, because we can pass whatever implementation we want. Just it must be able ot respond to the above methods...