# When using angular-cache is there any advantage to using the Angular LocalStorageModule?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage, angular-cache

The angular-cache can be set up like this:

```
app.service('myService', function ($angularCacheFactory) {

    // This cache will sync itself with localStorage if it exists, otherwise it won't. Every time the
    // browser loads this app, this cache will attempt to initialize itself with any data it had
    // already saved to localStorage (or sessionStorage if you used that).
    var myAwesomeCache = $angularCacheFactory('myAwesomeCache', {
        maxAge: 900000, // Items added to this cache expire after 15 minutes.
        cacheFlushInterval: 3600000, // This cache will clear itself every hour.
        deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive', // Items will be deleted from this cache right when they expire.
        storageMode: 'localStorage' // This cache will sync itself with `localStorage`.
    });
});
```

From what I understand if the storageMode is set to 'localStorage' then it handles backing up to localstorage itself.

I am already using the angular LocalStorageModule for other things.

Is there any advantage in me setting up a localStoragePolyfill and using the LocalStorageModule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, that the most powerfull usage of the `Cache` cooperating with `LocalStorage` could be found here:  [`.put(key, value, options)`](http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/api.html#cacheput)

As you can see, the third parameter, is the `options`, the setting for this key and value pair, **not** for the whole cache instance.

So we can call it like this

```
myAwesomeCache.put('someItem'
  , 'someValue'
  , { storageMode: 'localStorage', storageImpl: myLocalStoragePolyfill });
```

where `myLocalStoragePolyfill` is our wrapper of the local storage? or we can just use the built-in handler and pass it like `{ storageMode: 'localStorage' }`

So, having this, what is the real advantage? we can cache some really stable, constant settings (if there are any). An example could be some Metadata, complex configuration for the application, which can hardly change.

So, **in case**, that we know, that **something is almost static**, we do have simple way how to use **standard cache**, while **improving peformance**...

*NOTE: local storage is not the same as memory cache. It stores a JSON type of objects. No methods! just string representation*

Comment: I think maybe you are confused about my question. Or perhaps I am confused with your answer. I am already using "storageMode: 'localStorage'".  What I want to know is if there is any advantage in using the Angular LocalStorageModule?  Can I just delete this from my application as it seems angular cache does everything I need?

Comment: @Melina Hmmm, well here I tried to explain different usage of the Local storage (without cache) http://stackoverflow.com/a/21229481/1679310. Other words, I would say, that these concept are different. They could live together, but I do use them differently. Static data (like Metadata or templates, or most importantly: **user customized settings**) do not have to be reloaded every time. They could should be ready for use next time... then local storage wins. While dynamic data could be cached only...

Comment: "we can just use the built-in handler and pass it like { storageMode: 'localStorage' } - Now you said that then is this needed: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage  or can you do everything that is needed with angular-cache only ?

Comment: @Melina, Do not get me wrong. I think that what you say is reasonable! really ;) I would say yes, enhanced cache could be the only solution. the only API... but I am not sure, if this is OK from design, maintenance perspective. Because in case, **when I would like to explictly use LocalStarage**... but I ma forced to use **API of the Cache** .. not as nice ... I guess you know what I mean ;).. but yes.. if you wish to use advanced cache only, why not. Othe words: `I see benefits in using cache cooperating with local storage. But I see benefits to use them separately as well`